# Pass a Parameter to a Stored Procedure using ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I am doing a simple project on Visual Studio 2013 about a book library.
I have a database from which I will get the information for the `GridView`'s.

The purpose of this page is to display the list of authors and their respective titles.

So, basically, I have a `GridView` which will display the author's names and IDs.
I added a column to the end and edited it as a template so I could include another `GridView` - this one will contain the book titles for the respective author in the first `GridView`.

The first `GridView` is connected to a first `ObjectDataSource` which will call a function `GetData()` (which will return the right table to be shown on the `GridView`).
The second `GridView` is connected to a second `ObjectDataSource` which will call a function `GetTitlesByAuthor()`. **But**, this function receives an argument: the `au_id` (author_ID).

My problem is: How can I pass the parameter `au_id` depending on the value of the `au_id` displayed on the first `GridView` rows?

**EDIT**: To be more clear:

I have a `GridView` with 3 columns (`au_id`, `au_name`, `titles`). I set the `titles` field to be a template so I could insert a gridview in the `ItemTemplate` section. That `GridView` will contain only a collumn with all the titles from a specific `au_id` (depending on the outter `GridView` row's `au_id` value). My problem is obtaining that value to send to the second `ObjectDataSource` containing a list of the titles.
So my final table would be something like:

```
au_id    au_name    titles
--------------------------
1        Gary       A Book Title
                    Another Book I Wrote
2        Sarah      Cooking book
                    Tech Book
        ... and so on ...
```

This is my current code:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="au_id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="au_id" HeaderText="Author ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="au_id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="au_lname" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="au_lname" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="au_fname" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="au_fname" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Titles">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="au_id">
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/bullet.png" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" />
          </Columns>
          <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <RowStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetTitlesByAuthor" TypeName="MyStore.DataSet1TableAdapters.AuthorTitlesTableAdapter">
          <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="409-56-7008" Name="author_ID" Type="String" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="MyStore.DataSet1TableAdapters.AuthorsTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to change c# code.
So, to accomplish my goal I added an invisible `Label` next to the nested `GridView`, bound it to `au_id` and then configured the `ObjectDataSource` to get the parameter from the `Label`.

The resulting code is below:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="au_id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="au_id" HeaderText="Author ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="au_id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="au_lname" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="au_lname" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="au_fname" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="au_fname" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Titles">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("au_id", "{0}") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" BackColor="Transparent" DataKeyNames="au_id">
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/bullet.png" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
          </Columns>
          <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <RowStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetTitlesByAuthor" TypeName="MyStore.DataSet1TableAdapters.AuthorTitlesTableAdapter">
          <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="au_id" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="MyStore.DataSet1TableAdapters.AuthorsTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

ohh it's then nested gridview.I havent done work on objectdatasource but as I understand you have a main grid where you want to pass author id in child grid whuch shows books.

The way I would have done it..

```
protected void GVAuthor_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblauthid= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblCustomerID");//I dont know what is your grid source aspx so assuming it as label.               

            GridView GvBook = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GvBook");
            bindChildGridview(Convert.ToInt32(lblauthid.Text), GvBook); //Bind the child gridview here ..


        }
    }
 private void bindChildGridview(int authorId, GridView ChildGridview)
    {
        try
        {
            Get datasource based on authorId
            ChildGridview.DataSource = <<Your Datasource>>;                // Set DataSource Here
            ChildGridview.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Select parameters for ObjectDataSources are stored in the InputParameters array.  So, the value of the author id in the row needs to be added to this array.

Try this:

```
protected void GVAuthor_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           var authorId = e.Row.DataItem("au_id");
           var ods = e.Row.FindControl("ObjectDataSource2") as ObjectDataSource;
           ods.InputParamenters["author_ID"] = authorId; 
        }
    }
```

You also may need to remove the DataSource attribute in GridView2 in the aspx page, set it dynamically in the rowDataBound event and then call DataBind as @coder001 does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice approach described in msdn you can take a look [objectdatasouce parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581787.aspx).

Comment: The link you provided me does not help. I have a `GridView` with 3 columns (`au_id`, `au_name`, `titles`). I set the `titles` field to be a template so I could insert a gridview in the `ItemTemplate` section. That `GridView` will contain only a collumn with all the titles from a specific `au_id` (depending on the outter `GridView` row's `au_id` value). My problem is obtaining that value to send to the second `ObjectDataSource`.